# Python package for processing GRIB data in windows

Tags: python, software-recommendations, radar, grib, precipitation

I would like to know what python packages can be used to process GRIB (Gridded Binary) data on a Windows system. I know there is something called pygrib, but to use that I have to use cygwin windows installation (something I want to avoid).

I am looking for the package to streamline the processing of gridded precipitation data available from NCDC website (for example: http://data.eol.ucar.edu/codiac/dss/id=21.093). NCDC delivers the archived gridded precipitation data as: Unix Compressed (.Z) Gridded Binary (GRIB) Format

Currently I use NOAA Climate and Weather Toolkit (http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/), but this adds another level of processing (something I want to avoid).

I am seeking python packages, and workflow, perhaps with some examples to automate the seamless processing of GRIB files to derive the precipitation data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL can read grib files and can talk to python, so it should be no problem to use it on Windows.

You don't need cygwin to use GDAL, take a look at the binaries provided by http://gisinternals.com/sdk